# .Net how should i share session objects between different layers of asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a List objects when application starts and saved them as a session variable.

I then use this session variable throughout life of the application.

At times I update to this List in other layers of the application so I want to pass this session variable to other layers.

Should I be passing List object from asp.net to other layers in the methods? should i create a property of List in all layers which are going to use this object and set the property from the presentation layer? if i create a static list then all users see same list. i want the list to be session specific.

Comment: Why are storing an object in the session that must exist throughout life of the application? That sounds like an ideal candidate for the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx). Session is unique for every user.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, Cache is shared between different Sessions ...

Comment: @platon: correct, and it's lifetime is exactly the lifetime of the application unlike Session, hence i was wondering if the OP is using the Session in a wrong way.

Comment: @Tim, the task is to maintain it session specific...

Comment: @platon: then it's lifetime shouldn't be at the application level...also, cache does NOT have to be shared.

Comment: @Chris Lively, here is the link to SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492043/data-cache-vs-session-object-in-asp-net.  I did not find this info in MSDN though...

Comment: i want to maintain session specific list

Comment: @platon: there are many types of caching providers.  The one built into MS is only one.

Comment: @Chris Lively, I thought we were talking here about standard cache providers.  nothing else were mentioned here ...  Taking into consideration other providers, you are definitely right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not send a session object to your data layers or other business logic.  One of the primary reasons for even separating those things out is so that you can reuse the code in other programs.

As soon as you add a dependency, like on HttpContext, then you may as well not have those layers and just throw it all together.

Regarding the list itself, when you need to pass the data to the business / data layers send it as a List.

Finally, I would suggest that unless that list is used on a large number of the pages that you don't put it in session at all and instead just pull the data from the database whenever it's needed.  Session data has to be serialized and deserialized on each page access.  This adds processing overhead.  It gets worse if your app is in a load balanced environment because the session data would have to be pushed and pulled across the network wire for every page access whether or not it was used... which neatly takes away any reason for having it in session anyway.

However, if the data is used in most places then I'm really curious as to what it is.  Session shouldn't be used as a dumping ground for a bunch of objects.  And I'm really hoping you are not trying to store things like datasets, command objects, or anything like that.

Comment: the list is a collection of objects that other layers are updating if the underline data which the object is mapping to updates. only then i want to update the existing list that is stored in the session because i dont want to lose the changes that other classes have been making on the list

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: I would highly suggest you don't use session.  Instead, have a set of tables that store this information to maintain your state.  When the values should really be committed, copy that data into the real tables.  With session you have the potential of running into memory issues, lost data due to app restarts, and lots of other things that could really piss people off.  Especially if, as it sounds, that this work might take longer than a few minutes to put together.

Comment: the project doesn't use database. we are building it with queues.

Answer (score 4):

I would write the other layers of your application to accept and return list of objects, they shouldn't be aware or care that the list is being stored after they're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

I will never use Session variables in DataAccess Layer or Business Layer. It's like going against the design. I will rather pass a value of the session variable in the function's parameter in the Data Access Layer or Business Layer which intents to use that Session variable

Answer (score 0):

Your Session variable is available using the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[....]
```

So, you need to create an additional properly only to reduce the code.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session in class libraries i.e. data layer?

Comment: The Current is a static property of the HttpContext class.  So, if you need to obtain a Session object specific for a certain context, there is no need to pass it.  It is available through this code.

Comment: sorry im lost. is there a link that explains this that you're explaining that i can access session objects in other layers?

Comment: I would agree, that it is better to save the List object as a List instead of trying to access the Session variable.  Nevertheless, this code would work, this will result in a bad design and difficult to support code in the future.