# Choosing Cache versus Session to store data in a web forms application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I just want to know about ASP.NET cache and I'll just put my question on this simple example.

I use cache on a page "samplepage.aspx" (*I am not using this method right now.*)

```
// upon entering of the samplepage.aspx, assign user id to cache
Cache["loginid"] = Login.Id.ToString();
```

user1 enters on that page and currently using that cache object.
Eventually, user2 enters also on the same page which is the "samplepage.aspx" while user1 is currently logon.

Now my question is, will the Login.Id of the user2 could overwrite the cache "loginid" which the user1 already assigned its Login.Id?

Or it will create another memory for cache object for user2? And if I put a List (let's say a list of 5000 employees) into cache, could it affect my system's performance? Also, which consumes more memory, cache or session if I put the same data in them?

I used session before but I want to know if cache could behave like session. Thanks for the answers.

**EDIT:**
@TimMedora, thanks for your comment but what if the list was filtered every event of a certain user on that page? Example if a user1 click button_filterLastNameOnly, and user1 will click another button_filterFirstNameOnly. As you see, that list will be filtered based on the event of the user1. I don't know where to save that list because I read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx) about reducing round trips from the database so I want to save that list on a cache or a session.

Comment: `Session` is probably the right choice for a user-specific ID. `Cache` can behave similarly, but it puts the onus on you to use/track unique keys. `Cache` is probably the right choice for a list of 5000 items. You certainly wouldn't want such a list being stored on a user-by-user basis.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492043/data-cache-vs-session-object-in-asp-net. 

Basicly, for user specific objects, use the session.

Comment: @TimMedora, thanks for your comment but what if the list was filtered every event of a certain user on that page? Example if a user1 click button_filterLastNameOnly, and user1 will click another button_filterFirstNameOnly. As you see, that list will be filtered based on the event of the user1. I don't know where to save that list because I read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx) about reducing round trips from the database so I want to save that list on a cache or a session.

Comment: You can cache the list once, and then filter it just for the page. As long as you don't update the cached version with the filtered version, you should be fine (this can be tricky). Or you could go back to the database and filter on the fly...5000 records is nothing for a well-structured, well-indexed SQL Server database.

Comment: @TimMedora, wow. Dude you helped me a lot. I get your point. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I want to mark your comment as the answer but unfortunately I don't know how to. Anyway, I'll use your idea to my project. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache performance is good so don't worry about using it.

In your example, it is much better to save your user information in the Session because it is a unique information for each user. If you wanted to save something common for all users, then you could go for Cache.

Answer (score 2):

See [Data cache vs session object in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492043/data-cache-vs-session-object-in-asp-net).

Basically, for user specific objects (like in your case, the user id), use the session.
For object shared by all user, use cache.